# php code duplicates rows when exporting to excel

Tags: php, mysql, excel

I have to following code, when it runs it will duplicate blank rows or it will duplicate other rows that are full of data and i done understand why?

```
$filename = date("Y-m-d_g-i-a");    

// output headers so that the file is downloaded rather than displayed
header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$filename.'.csv"');

// create a file pointer connected to the output stream
$output = fopen('php://output', 'w');

// output the column headings
fputcsv($output, array('ID', 'P.O #', 'Date', 'To', 'Time', 'Vin', 'Reason', 'Amount', 'Employee #', 'Mananger', 'Account #', 'Store Location', 'Borrowed', 'verified','Adjustment','Adjustment by','','VOID','Emp Name'));

// fetch the data
mysql_connect('******', '*******', '******');
mysql_select_db('********');
$rows = mysql_query('SELECT fpo.*, users.name FROM fpo LEFT OUTER JOIN users ON (fpo.empnum = users.empnum)');

// loop over the rows, outputting them
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rows)) fputcsv($output, $row);
```

Comment: did you confirm that your query is returning the proper results in the first place?

Comment: Yes it is working right.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` you will get more than one row in your result if one of these conditions are true:

```
The values in table fpo, column empnum are not unique
The values in table users, column empnum are not unique
```

You can propably fix this by changeing your query to something like this:

```
SELECT fpo.*, users.name 
FROM fpo 
LEFT OUTER JOIN users 
ON (fpo.empnum = users.empnum)')
GROUP BY users.name
;
```

But without more information about your data this is guessing only...

Comment: The above code did not work. I just get a white page now with no errors. What other data do you need?

Comment: Is one of the conditions I mentioned true for your data?

Comment: I got it the comma was in the wrong spot here is the correct code `$rows = mysql_query('SELECT fpo.*, users.name FROM fpo LEFT OUTER JOIN users ON (fpo.empnum = users.empnum)GROUP BY users.name');` how ever it only gives me 156 Results. There is well over 5000 rows in the db